# MongoDB C# offi: multi OR query like searching Tags

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I searching to get all contents that are tagged with some Tags. $OR can't be nested in MongoDB but what about make a multi OR query in C# driver using a List of Tags or List of string?. Using a QueryComplete or some StringBuilder to build an Or(tag1,tag2 params..tagn), what is the method to query the taggeds contents using multi OR statement?

thanks.

```
var query=new QueryComplete[];
List<Tags> tags=new List<Tags>();
foreach(Tag tag in tags)
{

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
List<QueryComplete> myarray = new List<QueryComplete>();
foreach(Tag t in Tags)
{
  myarray.Add(Query.EQ(TagName, t.TagName));
}

var query = Query.Or(myarray.ToArray());
```

Comment: Imagine recursive OR statement like foreach(Tag tag in tags){ query=Query.Or(query,Query.EQ("tag.Name",tag.Name))} you will nested the tags and you can't.

Answer (score 1):

There is [$in](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24in) operator in mongodb, seems it more fit for above task:

```
List<Tags> tags=new List<Tags>();
Query.In("TagName", BsonArray.Create(tags.Select(x=> x.Name)));
```